# How to get category name from URL and pass to a template

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm using the following page template to display the posts in a single category and plan to format the first post differently than the others. This works as desired but I have the category_name hard coded in the template. I want to use this template for several different categories and would like to learn how to pass the category_name to the template from a link.

For example, the link to the desired page using the special template is http://wildcatweb.net/5th/ and '5th' is also the category_name. How do I tell the template to get the category_name from the URL and use it in the template?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: pageAssignments
*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="small-12 large-8 columns" id="content" role="main">
<header>
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        </header>

  <!-- show latest post FULL -->

 <?php query_posts('showposts=1&category_name=5th'); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="lastest-post">



     <h2 class="pagetitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

</div><!--close .latest-post -->

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?><!-- end lastest post -->

 <!-- show older post excerpts -->

<?php query_posts('showposts=5&offset=1&category_name=5th'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="older-post">

         <h3 class="pagetitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"     rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    </div><!--.older-post -->

<?php endwhile; endif; ?><!-- end past-entry -->

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: If they are both the same category, why the double query when you already have the data available in the first on?

Comment: I posted my question to another forum also and received an answer that met my needs. Here's the link to the solution that help me: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128336/how-to-get-category-name-from-url-and-pass-to-a-template/128345?noredirect=1#128345

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$category_name = explode ('',$current_url);
$category_name = $category_name['3'];
query_posts('showposts=1&category_name='. $category_name);
```

Comment: I don't think query_posts sanitizes, so you are creating an SQL injection with your code. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] needs to be sanitized.